# Online booking bot SQL logic

Tags: python, sql, rdbms

I'm making a movie ticket bot but I'm stuck at the point what if someone is received the data
available data from mysql which will be updated by someone in next few seconds...
As there may be a situation where first one didn't completed booking procedure ...but the second one did..

Then how to handle the database so that I can get real time data no matter how many users are there.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Design this application" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

When some one starts booking procedure you show the available seats. If he/she selects any number of seat to book then you should mark those as booked (thought it's not been confirmed yet) to avoid this situation.

You might mention to him that it's been booked only for 5 minutes. If he/she doesn't complete the booking within this time limit then the booking will automatically be cancelled.

For this 5 minutes those seats will not be available to anyone to book. But soon after his/her failure to complete the booking within 5 minutes or cancelling the booking those seats will be available to everyone else.

Comment: So I have to whole SQL data in a file then reading it then when the user reaches the seat booking I should the SQL query right?

Comment: When user reaches the seat booking part you will marked his selected seats as booked for a period of time. So those will not be available to anyone else.